# How can I fix issue about wrong character output in my Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

yesterday I've tried some installations/upgrades of node, Ruby etc. via homebrew. Since that my terminal output on my Mac is unreadable. Looks like wrong character encodings. But after restarting the machine, restarting terminal, starting `bash` within my `zsh`-terminal didn't change the wrong encoding.

Output looks like really cryptic but selecting text and pasting it to an editor everything is correct in the editor. Any idea?
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: why don't change / reset the font setting? it's not encoding issue if you can copy the text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you! You were right. Changing the font solved my issue but I'm not sure why the font was broken since yesterday.